# Access window object from VSCode Extension

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I need to know if the instance where the extension is running is focused or not. For that I want to use the window.document.isFocused() method.

Is there any way to access the window object from the extension? If not, is there any method in the vscode api that can achieve the same functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, extensions cannot access VS Code's DOM.

VSCode loads at most one instance of an extension per window. To determine if an editor within the window is active or not, try the `window.activeTextEditor` property and the `window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor` event: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_window

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I want to determine the focused window, not editor. In the case that multiple VSCode windows are open.